# Does Mulesoft have a telemetry or system metadata API for user and usage data?

Tags: mulesoft

Does Mulesoft have an API for metadata? E.g.:

- Total number of users (from my organization)
- Number of systems connecting
- Number of APIs in use
- Usage statistics per api

Thanks,
Keith :)

Comment: Question lacks focus. What have you investigated? Try reading the documented APIs first: https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/portals/anypoint-platform/